# Finite *covering* groups that act freely on some sphere

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology

A remarkable result (reviewed [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group%20actions%20on%20spheres#GeneralObstructionToAndExistenceOfFreeActions)) -- going back, at least, to P. A. Smith, developed by Cartan & Eilenberg and Milnor, and culminating in the theorem of Madsen, Thomas & Wall -- characterizes those finite groups which admit a free continuous action on a topological sphere in at least one dimension.

I am wondering about the following more general question:

- Which finite groups are *covered* by (i.e.: receive a surjective homomorphism from) a finite group that acts freely on some topological sphere?

For example ([here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group%20actions%20on%20spheres#FiniteSubgroupsOfSUTwoSatisfyTheSmithAndTheMilnorCondition)), there are dihedral groups of order $2 p$ (for a prime number $p$) which thus violate Milnor's "$2 p$-condition" and hence cannot have any free action on any sphere; but their double cover by the corresponding binary dihedral group does have a free action on the 3-sphere (namely by regarding the binary dihedral group as a subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2) \simeq S^3$).

So I am wondering how generic this situation is. Maybe all finite groups can be covered by ones that act freely on some sphere?

Looking at the above example, one sees that the double cover of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ by $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ remains non-trivial on all non-cyclic subgroups, whereby the order of all non-cyclic subgroups is multiplied by 2 under the extension, so that Smith/Cartan&Eilenberg's [$p^2$-condition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group%20actions%20on%20spheres#EquivalentVersionsOfPSquareCondition) and Milnor's [$2 p$-condition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group%20actions%20on%20spheres#Milnor2PCopndition) are enforced.

This seems to suggest a strategy for how to understand finite covering groups freely acting on some sphere in more generality. Maybe it's easy, but I am not sure yet.

Answer (score 11):

For a group to act freely on a sphere (even on a homotopy sphere), it must not have subgroups of the form $\mathbb Z/p \times \mathbb Z/p$ (this is the $p^2$-condition you mention). It follows that its Sylow subgroups are all cyclic or generalized quaternion.

Thus, for groups whose cover acts freely on a (homotopy) sphere, their Sylow subgroups must be cyclic, generalized quaternion, or dihedral (as a Sylow subgroup of a quotient is a quotient of a Sylow subgroup by Sylow's thorems).

Groups satisfying this condition were called $\mathcal P'$-groups by Wall, and classified in his article *[On the structure of finite groups with periodic cohomology](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4614-7193-6_16)*.

This is only a necessary condition and not (necessarily) sufficient, but it seems very stringent. One could look through this list for examples where the 2p condition fails, to see if it fails also on every cover.

Comment: But how "to see if it fails also on every cover"? That seems to be the question, no?

Comment: @UrsSchreiber Well, we're only interested in the covers that are also $\mathcal P'$-groups, so one only needs to look at covers that appear also in the classification of those.

Comment: I see, I was misreading. The point of the argument is that there are finite groups none of whose covers can have a free action on a sphere. Thanks!

Comment: @UrsSchreiber There was also a typo in my original post that made that unclear.